# file not found error when setting the environment variable in docker compose yml file

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, google-cloud-speech

I am setting the  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable from within my docker-compose.yml file. This is the structure of my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "2"

services:

  server:
    container_name: server

    environment:
        - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/dir1/dir2/file1.json
```

My JSON file is present in the above directory. From my python code, which is also run as part of Docker container, I am using Google Speech API like this:

```
import io
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types

#take speech wav file and turn it into text. return text
def transcribe_file(speech_file):
    """Transcribe the given audio file."""
    client = speech.SpeechClient()
```

When I execute above it throws error that `google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File /dir1/dir2/file1.json was not found.`

I am unable to understand why it is not able to find the JSON when it is present in the correct directory.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're adding `/dir1/dir2/file1.json` to your Docker image or mounting it as a volume. Having the file present at that location on the host isn't sufficient.

Comment: how do I add the file to my docker image? I am new to Docker so not sure about that

Comment: So I will have to add `COPY /dir1/dir2/file1.json  dire/` in mt `Dockerfile` to add the json to `dire` directory within my WORKDIR? And then what directory do I specify in my docker-compose.yml?